# Scooter stalls when idle

Tags: engine, stall, idle, scooter

I have a 1995 Yamaha Zuma sports scooter. It's a 2-stroke 50cc. Approx. 13,000km.

It hadn't been used in probably more than 10 years. I recently cleaned out the carburetor and put fresh fuel and oil in.

It starts and runs fine but if stationary in idle, the revs slowly decrease until it stalls.

We've adjusted the idle speed up but it still stalls when stopped; Eg. Red lights, stop signs, in traffic etc.

When stationary, to prevent it from stalling, I need to manually keep the revs up using the hand throttle (and break).

**Any suggestions on what to look for to solve this issue?**

A *temporary* solution I've been using so far is permanently giving it a *very small amount* of choke, preventing it from stalling when stopped; I understand this isn't practical and long-term.

Comment: How did you clean the carbs? It sounds like the idle jet may be clogged up a bit.

Comment: We took apart the carby and cleaned it by hand; draining old oil and gunk

Comment: If adding choke helps then your either getting too much air or not enough fuel. Chances are it's not enough fuel, Check your pilot jet for clogging, hold it up to the light to see. take the carb completley apart and clean in an ultrasonic cleaner.